# Using python to send email through TLS

Tags: python, email, ssl

I am trying to automate sending email through a python script. I am presently using an expect script to use openssl s_client to connect to the server. Presently we only use a certificate file along with the username password and it allows me to send the email. I found another question in which it was mentioned that in python you either need a hack to or a wrapper around the smtp class to use only the CA cert file and not the key file(which i don't have).

```
>>> smtpobj = smtplib.SMTP("mymailserver.com",465)
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 337, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 390, in getreply
+ str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The problem I am facing right now is that I am unable to connect to the server through python.

If I use the certificate file to connect through

```
smtplib.SMTP_SSL(myserver, port, certfile="mycert.cert")
```

then it throws the following error.

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:339: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

Please note, I am able to connect to the server using thunderbird, without a cert file. Any ideas, on how I can use python smtp(tls) to send the emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> smtpobj = smtplib.SMTP("mymailserver.com",465)
> smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> ```

This error has nothing to do with validation of the certificate. It is simply that you are using explicit TLS (i.e. STARTTLS command on plain connection) on a port which requires implicit TLS (TLS from start). Try this instead:

```
smtpobj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mymailserver.com",465)
```

Apart from that:

> ... you either need a hack to or a wrapper around the smtp class to use only the CA cert file and not the key file(which i don't have).

I think you mixing up some concepts:

- CA cert: this contains the trusted root which is needed to verify the certificate of the server. You don't have a key for this certificate and you don't need one.
- local cert, local key: these are used if the server requires authentication with a client certificate. In this case both cert and key are needed

What you probably want to specify is a CA cert in order to verify the servers certificate. Unfortunately smtplib does not give you a way to specify this CA certificate. You've tried certfile but this is used for specifying the local cert for client certificate authentication and it requires a key file.

The good news is: **it works without specifying a CA cert** because smtplib simply does not verify the servers certificate at all. The bad news is: because there is no verification of the server certificate **a man in the middle attack against the encrypted connection is easy**.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! 
SMTP_SSL worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the key pass phrase first using -

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out tempkey.pem
```

And then type passphrase once more -

```
openssl rsa -in mycert.pem -out tempkey.pem
openssl x509 -in mycert.pem >>tempkey.pem
```

Refer [this](https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#key-removepass) for more info.

Comment: I don't have a key(or if i do, its embedded in my cert).